# Can REMOTE_HOST contain more than one value?

Tags: apache-2.2

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers, the X-Forwarded-Host can contain more than one value:

```
Be careful when using these headers on the origin server, since they will contain more than one (comma-separated) value if the original request already contained one of these headers
```

Can REMOTE_HOST contain more than one value? 
Or it always be the single value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's true for `X-Forwarded-Host` just because there might be multiple proxies in between the original client and the server. The `REMOTE_HOST` is just a resolved name of `REMOTE_ADDR`, or NULL, if the resolution fails (i.e. no `PTR` exists or DNS is temporarily unavailable or the query times out). It's always a single value.

`REMOTE_ADDR` is always a single value usually referring to the direct client connecting the server. However, with [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html) you can alter this behaviour to get the originating useragent *even where that useragent is behind a load balancer, front end server, or proxy server*. That's useful when using load balancers and server side reverse proxies, while `X-Forwarded-Host` is suitable for client side proxies.